# Best way to cutting and concatenation integer operations

Tags: java, performance

What is the best way to cut an integer variable from another integer variable or concatenate two integer variables?

I mean, in the performance way? - I consider two options:

- cast an int to a String and perform a simple substring/concatenation operation and cast the String back to an int
- or perform an algorithmic operation, this way:

```java
    public static Integer concatenateInt(int a, int b) {
        if(b < 0){
            b *= -1;
        }
        int proxyB = b/10;
        a *= 10;
        for (; proxyB > 0; proxyB /= 10) {
            a *= 10;
        }

        if(a < 0){
            a -= b;
        } else {
            a += b;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

- via String:

```java
        return Integer.parseInt(a + "" + b);
```

The cutting of integer values will be a more complicated algorithm - so which way is preferred for best performance?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with performance until you know it is a problem. I'd start with the requirements, i.e. what exactly is cutting and concatenating? Do you mean 1 + 2 results in 12? The same as 12 + 3 or 1 + 23 would result in 123? What's the background for this? Why is this done with integers in the first place as it seems to be more of how you'd use strings?

Comment: But I'd bet that you will find that the first version is a lot faster ... if you do the benchmarking correctly.

Comment: Side note: `for (; b > 1; b /= 10)` would be wrong for a couple of reasons: 1) what if `b` is 0 or negative? 2) this loop changes `b` so after the loop it would be 0 (if it was positive to begin with)

Comment: (Well yea: I'm assuming that bugs are corrected before benchmarking :-) )

Comment: Well ... because such questions require either a guess, or someone to write a benchmark.  A guess is pointless, and the other alternative is you asking us to do a bunch of benchmark coding so that (probably just) you can learn something.  How about you just do the coding work yourself?

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi I really enjoyed this question, always fun getting to know the internal working of Java. Here is a oneliner to do the same :)
 (int) (number1 * Math.pow(10.0, Math.log10(number2) + 1.0) + number2);

Comment: @Reg, thanks. It seems I really have to test this code for performance handily. But I asked also because this is interesting for me also the memory performance. For example, if String operation will be faster, but from the point of opinion of more experienced developers - does the speed is decisive performance? - or memory use also should be counted? So, this is the reason why I did such a question. Only for other opinions knowing.